# How do you format php in html?

Tags: php, html

I have a simple `test.php` script:

```
<?php

    $name = $_GET['name'];
    $response = "Hi, ".$name."! How are you?";
    echo $response;

?>
```

I know I can echo the html script in the php like: `echo "<b>".$response."</b>";` but how can I just return the `$response` to my html page, and in the html page, it format the `$response` string?

I have a `index.html` page:

```
<title>Your name</title>
<center>Welcome to the coolest page ever</center>
<br>
"The PHP $response goes here"
<br>
<u>This is the footer</u>
```

As you can see, there is a html page with a template, and the response is required on one spot only (in the middle of the page). I don't want to echo the entire html script.

If I put the php script into the html, then my php script is exposed...

Example link: `www.domain.com/test.php?name=John`

Comment: you want to print the response variable in the specified html spot ?

Comment: @ⵍⵢⴻⵙ Yes, basically.

Comment: You could use Ajax

Comment: You could use `"The PHP <?php echo $response; ?> goes here"` if you would like to use PHP for this. You may need to add a PHP handler to enable PHP to execute on .html files, and the method will vary based on your server architecture (Apache/Nginx/IIS). You could also use javascript or jQuery to print the variables at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

save this page with whatever.php.

```
   <html>
   <title>Your name</title>
   <body>
   <center>Welcome to the coolest page ever</center>
   <br>
   <?php if(isset($_GET['name'])) { $response = "Hi, ".$_GET['name']."! How are you?"; 
   echo $response;}
   ?>
   <br>
   <u>This is the footer</u>
   </body></html>
```

Comment: If I do this, people can see my php code from view source or inspect element

Comment: php code never show in front-end. only echo text will show in browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the html in your php page test.php

Here is an example of how I have used echo inside of html to display a value

First do your php to connect to your database and execute whatever query you want

I use includes as well to make dealing with the header/Navigation and footer simple for every page. Instead of having to have that code inside of your test.php page you can create separate pages and just include them. That way if you want to edit your header or footer you can do it in one place and it will change for all of your pages.
As you will see in my html you can then put the echo value into the html like so value="

```
//php code begins here
<?php

include_once 'header.php';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `person` WHERE person_id = " .$user_id." ";

$conn = mysqli_connect( $dbServername , $dbUsername , $dbPassword , $dbName );
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "user_id: " . $row["person_id"]. " - person_id: " . $row["person_first"]. " " . $row["person_last"]. "<br>";
    $person_id = $row["person_id"];
    $person_first = $row["person_first"];
}
} else {
echo $sql;
}
$conn->close();

?>
//first php section ends here


//html section starts here
<div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-md-12">First Name</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <input type="text" required="" name="person_first" value="<?php echo $person_first;?>" class="form-control form-control-line"> </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-md-12">Last Name</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <input type="text" required="" name="person_last" value="<?php echo $person_last;?>" class="form-control form-control-line"> </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="example-email" class="col-md-12">Mobile</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <input type="text" required="" name="person_mobile" value="<?php echo $person_mobile;?>" class="form-control form-control-line"> </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="example-email" class="col-md-12">Address</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <input type="address" required=""  name="person_address" value="<?php echo $person_address;?>" class="form-control form-control-line"> </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-md-12">Email</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <input type="text" required="" name="person_email" value="<?php echo $person_email;?>" class="form-control form-control-line"> </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-md-12">SSN</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <input type="text" required="" name="SSN" value="<?php echo $SSN;?>" class="form-control form-control-line"> </div>
                                    </div>
//html ends here

//php footer code starts here
<?php
include_once 'footer.php';
?>
// php footer ends here
```

Begin code for new page header.php

```
<?php
include 'includes/dbh.php';

session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION["u_id"]))
{
  header("location: login.php");
}


$user_id = $_SESSION['u_id'];
echo "UserID is '".$user_id."'";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id='$user_id'";
// $sql = "SELECT SINGLE `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE user_id = '".$user_id."'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "user_id: " . $row["user_id"]. " - Name: " . $row["user_first"]. " " . $row["user_last"]. "<br>";
    $displayname = $row["user_first"]. " " . $row["user_last"];
    $email = $row["user_email"];
    $uid = $row["user_uid"];
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM players WHERE player_id=$user_id";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "player_id: " . $row["player_id"]. " - player_id: " . $row["player_first"]. " " . $row["player_last"]. "<br>";
    $player_id = $row["player_id"];
    $player_first = $row["player_first"];
    $player_last = $row["player_last"];
    $player_mobile = $row["mobile"];
    $player_address = $row["player_address"];
    $player_city = $row["city"];
    $player_state = $row["state"];
    $player_zip = $row["zip"];
    $player_dob = $row["dob"];
    $player_gender = $row["gender"];
}
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

End header.php

Comment: If I do this, people can see my php code from view source or inspect element

Comment: So that is something you could do with the include. For example my header.php code which is included at the top of the page is not visible in this pages source.

Comment: I have added my header.php file above so you can see how that code works